# password issue with database change

Tags: php, database

I am changing my database to add an "sex" column and after, I can't log into the my site. So I look into the `get_passwd()` function, and I see `$passwd = $row[5]` is causing the problem.

I fixed it, but is there better way to do this function, even if I adding column into the database?

```
function get_passwd($link, $login) {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE email='$login'"; 
    $result = mysql_query($sql, $link);
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
    $passwd = $row[6];//this is the problem! 
    //echo $passwd;
    return $passwd;
};
```

Comment: `mysql_fetch_assoc` and `$passwd = $row['column_name']`. But you should avoid using `mysql_`, it is deprecated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're **MYSQL** functions are deprecated.
You should be afraid of **MYSQL Injections**.

---

*... But here is a way to make the world of **MYSQL** safer ...*

---

**PDO - http://php.net/manual/de/book.pdo.php**

**Example:**

```
$db = new PDO("mysql:host=$db_host;dbname=$db_name;charset=utf8", "$db_user", "$db_pass");
$query = $db->prepare("SELECT username, password FROM user WHERE email = ? LIMIT 1");
// you should know which columns you are selecting
// LIMIT to make sure you don't select 2 rows.
$query->execute(array($login));
$row = $query->fetch();
echo $row["password"];
//return $row["password"];
$db = null;
```

Comment: this project is almost 90 completed.  I do want to PDO or sqli. I am scare of break down the whole thing.

Answer (score 1):

Use `mysql_fetch_assoc` instead of mysql_fetch_array. It will return keyed array with column names as keys.

Comment: And I also recommend not to use an asterisk char in select statements. It's much safer and better to name every column you need.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that everyone will tell you that it is no longer recommended to use these functions and you should switch to something like [PDO](http://php.net/PDO), for example.

But since you might need to maintain some old application with legacy code I'm guessing that we can also stay on point and give an answer. You can use a function like [mysql_fetch_assoc](http://php.net/mysql_fetch_assoc) and the returned value will be an associative array, so you'll be able to use **$row['password']** instead of **$row[6]**. There's also [mysql_fetch_object](http://php.net/mysql_fetch_object).

Again, when you look at those manual pages please pay attention to the big notice on the red background at the top.

Comment: this project is almost 90 completed.  I didn't write in MVP or OOP format. It has to be out in one months' time. U tell me how to change it?

Answer (score 1):

`mysql_fetch_assoc` allows you to perform a mysql query and use the response object as a key[value] array.

```
function get_passwd($link, $login){
   $sql="SELECT * FROM user WHERE email='$login'"; 
   $result=mysql_query($sql, $link);
   $row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
   $passwd = $row['password']; <- use the column name here
   //echo $passwd;
   return $passwd;
};
```

Find out more at the documentation page below:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php